# How do I tell professors I am no longer applying to graduate school?

Tags: application, recommendation-letter

I can't tell if my email should be a be a casual heads up or a weighty explanation of how I fucked up.

I just graduated college and have been doing a number of side gigs, one of which was teaching English online, for money. I always knew I wanted to research this niche topic in educational media, so I have been preparing my applications since graduation and requested letters of recommendation from all these people.

Then out of the blue, I get a job offer from the company I've been teaching in English in to move to their office and work on producing educational media. **The industry sector, the job, and the country they are in is practically perfect.** So naturally I take the job.

Now I'm at a loss over how to tell my professors I'm putting a halt on my applications. I feel shitty for making them write letters that I won't use, and worse, I know I will be asking them again in a few years to apply again.

Is it common for people to give up on their applications like this?

Is there a polite way of emailing them **not only do I not need the letters anymore, but to also hang onto them because I will need them again?**

Comment: Just tell the truth. Anyone who's not a jerk will understand.

Comment: Tell them as soon as possible, and pretty briefly. "I got an unexpectedly great job offer, which I plan to take, so I will not apply this year. I still plan to go to graduate school in the near future, and appreciate all of your work in supporting me."

Comment: Definitely make sure to emphasize that you'll be applying again, too - probably your professors would rather write the letter now, when they remember the details a little better.

Answer (score 3):

You have a number of choices at your disposal:

- In person. I would recommend this as it offers the most rich (in terms of feedback) setting for you to explain your situation, offer your gratitude for their help thus far, and secure the notion that you would be revisiting your graduate applications down the road given your new job. However, given the fact that you may not be near your university, this option has its drawbacks.
- Through a Phone Call. Second to an in-person conversation is a phone call. You can receive more feedback in terms of their reaction to the news through audio cues. At the same time generating a more organic flow to the conversation.

> Now I'm at a loss over how to tell my professors I'm putting a halt on my applications. I feel shitty for making them write letters that I won't use, and worse, I know I will be asking them again in a few years to apply again.
>
> Is there a polite way of emailing them not only do I not need the letters anymore, but to also hang onto them because I will need them again?

As for email, here is something to consider:

> Dear [Professor X],
>
> I wanted to thank you for the time and effort that you have put into
>   writing a letter of recommendation for my graduate studies. I really
>   appreciate the help and advice you have given me through the process.
>
> I recently received an offer to work at [insert company here].
>   Although I had not considered it before, this position would allow me
>   to [insert reason here]. I have discussed this with [potentially other
>   professors, significant other] and I decided that this would be the
>   best move for me in the next couple of years.
>
> This does not mean that I do not have any aspirations to attend
>   graduate school however. I understand how you may be disappointed in
>   my decision, but I am hoping that you would support me if I were to
>   postpone my graduate studies and reapply down the road. I am wondering
>   if you would still be inclined to help me.
>
> Please let me know of any comments or reservations you may have about
>   this. Thank you.
>
> Respectfully Yours,
>
> [Your Name]

---

As for your questions:

> I can't tell if my email should be a be a casual heads up or a weighty explanation of how I fucked up.

Keep it simple and to the point. You did not fuck up, you are making the best (relatively speaking) decision for yourself at this point in time.

> Is it common for people to give up on their applications like this?

No hard data, but people quit programs for a multitude of reasons. You deciding to pursue a position is not the end of the world nor a unique situation.